# matlab control the digital camera

Tags: matlab, camera

I have a digital camera that doesn't support for taking a photo from the computer.

can I control this camera by matlab? or may I need a digital camera that supports it in order to control it by the matlab?

I just want to take a photo from matlab (there is a usb that is connected between the camera and the computer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to control cameras with Matlab you should have the Image Acquisition Toolbox. Additionally the camera you want to connect must be supported by the Toolbox.

You may want to check out
http://www.mathworks.com/products/imaq/

Answer (score 0):

In case your camera is also having A/V R output(like in Sony digital camera), you can use a USB TV Tuner for capturing the analog signal and then use matlab to capture the video/images in real time from camera. Works for me !!

Comment: But this solution does not allow to control the camera I guess.